# Переменная может быть не инициализирована

Tags: java, android, variable

При попытке компиляции получаю предупреждение:

```
int perc = 0
    ^^^^
The value of local variable perc is not used
```

Причем этой переменной я присваиваю значение ещё до
     setContentView.
Но ниже по списку ошибок и предупреждений вижу:

```
if (perc == 1){a = "";}
    ^^^^
The local variable perc may not have been initialized
```

P.S. прошу помочь с проблемкой. После if у меня идёт else, если что. Спасибо за помощь.

UPD: привожу кусочки кода для ясности:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B0, Bp, Bm, Bu, Br, Bv, Bd, BAC, Bc, Be, BF;
String a, s, s1, s2, s3, history, memory = "";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder cont = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
TextView tv, tv1, tv2;
ScrollView SV;
int b, c, d, g, l, width, height, p, result, resourceId, Ro = 0;
int perc = 0;
float f, f1, f2 = 0;
```

Тут я всё, что нужно, объявил, а perc специально вот так отдельно вынес (т.к. ошибка только в нем).

```
  OnClickListener Cl = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.BF:
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, menu.class);
startActivity(intent);
int perc = 1;
break;
```

Если будет нажата соответствующая кнопка - присвоить perc значение 1. Но, я считаю, что perc имел значение и до этого момента.
(( между верхним куском кода и нижним находится только та часть кода, которая находит элементы Layout ))

```
case R.id.B1:
if (Ro == 1){d = 0; tv1.setText(""); 
cont.append(builder).append("\n= ").append(memory).append("\n - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
a = "1";
builder.setLength(0);
Ro = 0;}
else{
if (perc == 1){a = "";}
else{a = "1";};};
break;
```

Здесь я пытаюсь использовать эту переменную для сравнения, но получаю ошибку.

Comment: Возможно, переменная объявляется в другой области видимости. Было бы хорошо, если бы вы привели цельный кусок кода, по которому можно уже будет определить связь ошибки с тем, как и где объявлена переменная

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо огромное, мне это действительно помогло

Comment: @pavlofff. Напишите свой комментарий как ответ, чтобы автор смог его ответить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы объявили две переменных perc: поле класса и локальную . При этом вам совершенно справедливо заметила IDE, что одна не используется, а вторая может не проинициализироваться. У второй нужно убрать `int` и таким образом обращаться к полю класса, а не создавать другую локальную переменную с таким же именем.

создать новую переменную с именем var и присвоить ей 1.

```
int  var = 1
```

присвоить уже созданой ранее переменной var значение 1

```
var = 1
```

Более подробно об этом  можно узнать, посмотрев про области видимости переменных и их перекрытие при совпадении имен.